# Create multiple database in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

I'm presently working on a project that requires a login(database created for that). But I'd also like to create another database for another sub-project (within the same project) e.g Create Event.
I'm using node js && mongoDB, considering I could only make one connection in app.js, how exactly can I go about the new database without interfering with the user credentials.